# Javascript validation: Block special characters From input text box when click on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

How can I restrict  entering special characters in the text box (txt_edition) by editing below code for validation? I want only numbers to be entered.

```
<script>
function validateForm() 
{
var x = document.forms["frm_bokAdd"]["txt_edition"].value;
if (x==null || x=="") 
{
    alert("Edition must be filled out");
    return false;
} 
</script>
```

Below is my form

```
<form  name="frm_bokAdd" action ="#"  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
<table border="0" align="center">
    <tr><td> <input type="text" name="txt_edition" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td> <input type="submit" name="bookIns_submit" value="Add"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that where *x* is the value of a form control, then `x == null` will always be false. Simply test if `/\D/.test(x)` returns true then *x* contains non–digit characters.

Comment: Do you want the field to accept '.' and how many number should be allowed after '.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I restrict entering special characters in the text box (txt_edition)

Don't. Allow users to arrive at a valid value any way they like, you really only care that the value is valid when it's sent to the server, and even then you should validate there too.

> by editing below code for validation? I want only numbers to be entered.

Just test when the form is submitted, passing a reference to the form in the call:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" >
```

and the function:

```
function validateForm(form) {
  var value = form.txt_edition.value;

  if (/\D/.test(value) || value == '') {
    alert("Edition must be filled out and contain only numbers");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can use this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" >
```

**JS**(at end of Body )

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**[DEMO is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FqRQm/)**

Answer (score 0):

use regex.

```
if (x.match(/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/) !== null) {
   //text is only numbers (use /^[0-9]*$/ for integers)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-size: 9pt;
                font-family: Arial;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Alphanumeric value:
        <input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;"
            onpaste="return false;" />
        <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Special Characters not allowed</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var specialKeys = new Array();
            specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
            specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
            specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
            specialKeys.push(36); //Home
            specialKeys.push(35); //End
            specialKeys.push(37); //Left
            specialKeys.push(39); //Right
            function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
                var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
                document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
                return ret;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expression -

```
    var edition = document.getElementById('txt_edition').value;
    outputVal = edition.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g,"");       
    if (edition != outputVal) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the key press like below,

```
function restrict_letters(e) {
    var keyCode = e . keyCode == 0 ? e . charCode : e . keyCode;
    // only 0 to 9
    if (keyCode < 48 && keyCode > 57) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

you can get more key codes in [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Also change the html function call like below,

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return restrict_letters(event)">
```

Note: function call need to give for the input field not for the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

To allow user to enter only number and dot. Use this regular expression

```
 function NumAndTwoDecimals(event , obj){
    reg = /[^0-9.,]/g;
    obj.value =  obj.value.replace(reg,"");
 }
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cN7dM/)

HTML code is

```
<input id="txtId" type="text" onkeyup="NumAndTwoDecimals(event , this);"></input>
```

To restrict user to enter only two number after '.' operator use

```
 function NumAndTwoDecimals(e , field) {
    var val = field.value;
    var re = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;
    var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)/g;
    if (re.test(val)) {
        //do something here

    } else {
        val = re1.exec(val);
        if (val) {
            field.value = val[0];
        } else {
            field.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPEUC/)